# SELinux allow process to execute binary

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, selinux, bacula

I have the Bacula backup system running and SELinux is interfering.

The problem arises when Bacula runs a script that invokes `/usr/bin/hostname` before one of the backups.

`12-Apr 00:05 dir_backup JobId 122: BeforeJob: /usr/local/sbin/sshbacula: line 13: /usr/bin/hostname: Permission denied`

This succeeds when SELinux is in permissive mode.

It is a very minor problem but I cannot fix it without running SELinux in permissive mode or by running Bacula unconfined entirely.

How do I allow Bacula to execute the hostname binary?

Comment: What was in the audit log?

Comment: I have not checked but I am pretty sure that it is because /usr/bin/hostname has the hostname_exec_t context and Bacula is then not allowed to run it. I'm not sure if possible, but can I somehow allow Bacula access to hostname_exec_t?

Comment: Let's not make wild guesses. You can get a good answer and know you have solved the problem if you actually get the real data from the audit log and work with that.